# Probability Measure of Infinite Number of Singleton Sets

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I have a pretty basic question which for sure have a very obvious explanation but I could not figure out:

Let's assume that our sample space consists of real numbers in the interval $[0,1)$. We know that probability measure of every singleton set is $0$. Now, what I think is, since our sample space includes infinite number of singleton sets, its probability measure should also be $0$, since we are only doing infinite summation of zeros. However probability measure of the sample space is equal to $1$. So, where am I doing wrong?

Comment: In probability (or measure theory), things add under countable disjoint unions only.  For precisely the reason you point out, you can't ask that they add under uncountable unions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that the usual probability space, with the Lebesgue measure on $[0, 1]$ (or $[0, 1)$, if you prefer), takes care of things for us.  Measures only require countable additivity, whereas the cardinality of any interval (such as the entire interval) is uncountable, so there is no contradiction in each individual point having probability $0$, but the entire interval having probability $1$.

This is why we can have a uniformly distributed continuous random variable from $0$ to $1$, but not a uniformly distributed random variable on the natural numbers.

Answer (score 2):

If your space were countable and every singleton set had measure zero, then your reasoning would be correct that the measure of the entire space would be 0. However, the way typical measure is defined, if your space is uncountable, you cannot conclude that if every singleton has measure zero then the space has measure zero. Think about how the integral of a non-zero constant function over an interval is $0$ if the two endpoints are the same, but non-zero if the two endpoints are different. You can't simply "add" all the zeros you get for every choice of equal end-points of the interval and then conclude the integral of the constant function is zero when the two endpoints are different.